# Assumptions of a mediation

Tags: r, mediation

Does anyone know the assumptions of a mediation- I can't find a clear answer anywhere! Should I consult regression assumptions?

I am only doing a simple mediation x > m > y using the mediation package on r.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Answering *"assumptions of mediation"* sounds like a research project starting with reading the academic article(s) associated with the process (theory) and the package (implementation). For the former (theory), [stats.se] is far better a site for discussing this topic; for the latter (implementation), I suggest knowing more about the theory before asking if the package executes it correctly would be prudent. Regardless, this question is not about programming so is off topic for StackOverflow. Good luck!

Comment: Mediation testing a la Baron Kenny contains, among other things, an assumption of unconfoundedness. Meaning that for each of the arrows relating x to m, m to y, and potentially x to y (direct effect), no confounder is biasing effect. Not sure the R package gets to that depth.